# Shopify [Plus] Liquid to Retrieve Orders & Customers, or Include App Proxy Snippets

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm looking for a way in Liquid to retrieve all Customers, or all Orders. I know it's targeted from a Client POV so probably not, but I just wanted to double check if there are any undocumented handles anyone has come across? *Its for a protected page for staff user only access.*

If the only solution to fetch this data is to use the App Proxy (for API access), is there a tidy way of including the output in a template? I gather there is no way to simply *include* an App Proxy liquid file into a Page as you can with Snippets, so does that purely leave either having the webpage at a proxy url or to pull in the contents with a jQuery call?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing. If you're on the front-end of a store, using Liquid, it seems pretty obvious you cannot easily access all customers. That would not be a front-end store thing. If you were logged in as a customer, with Liquid you'd have all that customer's order data.

With a clearer question, maybe you might get more help. What are you trying to do, and why?